next.ui button different on hover that disabled even though it shouldn't
<ButtonGroup className="rounded-xl shadow-sm shadow-black w-69" radius="sm">
    {buttons.map((button) => (
      <Button
        size="lg"
        className="font-bold text-xl  border-y-1 border-l-1 active:outline-0  disabled:border-cyan py-6 px-7  hover:bg-cyan/100 hover:border-cyan bg-blue-dark border-blue-black  text-white hover:text-white disabled:bg-cyan disabled:text-black disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-100 hover:opacity-100!important "
        isDisabled={button.disabledCondition}
        key={button.key}
        onClick={button.onClickFunction}
      >
        {button.label}
      </Button>
    ))}
</ButtonGroup>

The finance is on hover and for some reason it is different than disabled both have 100% opacity
I don't get why this happens - I have tried everything
button
theme: {
    colors: {
      purple: "#4c025f",
      cyan: "#00D8FF",
      pink: "#ff49db",
      orange: "#ff7849",
      green: "#13ce66",
      yellow: "#ffc82c",
      "gray-dark": "#273444",
      gray: "#8492a6",
      "gray-light": "#d3dce6",
      white: "#ffffff",
      "blue-black": "#1f2937",
      "blue-dark": "#18212f",
      black: "#000000",
      ...nextui.colors,
    },
    extend: {},

